# Probability of measuring an arbitrary eigenvalue for an observable with non-degenerate discreate spectrum, system in mixed state

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am mostly concerned with the correct notation, so I can be able to derivate the correct expression regarding the prob. of measuring an arbitrary eigenvalue $a_n$ of an observable $A$ that has a discrete non-degenerate spectrum, while the system is in a mixed state.

I will start with a simple case, so that it is easier for people to understand what I mean.

If we consider a system in a pure state and we make a measurement of some physical measurable quantity, that has a corresponding Hermitian operator in quantum mechanics. We also assume that the eigenstates of it, form a basis in the Hilbert space of the system. There are two ways of writing down the state of the system:

1. $|\psi\rangle$ which can be expressed via the eigenstates of $A$.
2. Via the density operator $\rho=|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$

When trying to find the prob. of measuring $a_n$, we have:

$P(a_n)=|c_n|^2=|\langle\phi_n|\psi\rangle|^2$.

Now, what if the state of the system is a mixed state. The only way of representing the mixed state is via the density matrix:

$\rho=\sum_kP_k|\psi_k\rangle \langle \psi_k|$. Now how or rather what is the correct way of writing the expression for  the prob. of measuring an eigenstate $a_n$ of $A$:

$P(a_n)=|c_n|^2=|\langle\phi_n|??????|^2$ What do we put in the question marks?

Comment: You know $P_k$ and you know the probability of state $\left | \psi_k \right >$ yielding $a_n$. So this is conditional probability.

Comment: How do I know the probability of state $|\psi_k\rangle$ yielding $a_n$? Plus, can't I make the claim that $|\psi_k\rangle=\sum_n c_{n(k)}|u_n\rangle$, meaning $|\psi_k\rangle$ can be expressed as linear combination of the eigenstates of an observable, for which we are making a measurement ?

Comment: You wrote it (without the k subscript) under point 2.